# CSS nth-child for greater than and less than

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In my HTML I have,

```
<div class="container">
</div>
<div class="container">
</div>
<div class="container">
</div>
<div class="container">
</div>
..................
..................
```

In the above HTML I have the `container` class. In my CSS, I need to add some styles to `.container:nth-child(3,4,5,6,..and so on)`. Means I need to apply all `nth-child` beside 1 and 2.

Comment: I think this is easier done with jQuery... You can use :nth-child() as selector for jquery.. You can also do `$(".container:nth-child("+Index+")")` where index is a dynamic number that you change in order to select the correct container.

Comment: I think using jQuery this also should work. You can change value of count variable as per your need. 

http://jsfiddle.net/qEH5Q/1/

Comment: I disagree: there's no reason to use jQuery (or Javascript, for that matter) to apply styles like this that are possible to achieve in well-supported CSS. This is styling, not behaviour, so CSS should almost always be the preferred solution for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

#### Update

[CSS Selectors Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#the-nth-child-pseudo) has introduced the new [`of <selector>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#the_of_selector_syntax) syntax by which we can target the `nth` element from the list of elements matching the `<selector>`.

E.g. `:nth-child(n+3 of div.container)` will match the 3rd, 4th, 5th, ... `div.container` elements, no matter if they are not the 3rd, 4th, 5th, ... elements of their parent.

From the Spec:

> [Example 49](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#example-3c07f717)
>
> By passing a selector argument, we can select the Nth element that matches that selector. For example, the following selector matches the first three “important” list items, denoted by the .important class:
>
> `:nth-child(-n+3 of li.important)`
>
> Note that this is different from moving the selector outside of the function, like:
>
> `li.important:nth-child(-n+3)`
>
> This selector instead just selects the first three children if they also happen to be "important" list items.

```css
:nth-child(n+3 of div.container) {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>1st</div>
  <div>2nd</div>
  <div>3rd</div>
  <div class="container">4th</div>
  <div class="container">5th</div>
  <div class="container">6th</div>
  <!--                   ^-- 6th element of its parent,
                             3rd of `div.container` list -->
  <div>7th</div>
  <div class="container">8th</div>
  <!--                   ^-- 8th element of its parent,
                             4th of `div.container` list -->
  <div>9th</div>
</div>
```

It is worth noting that [the support of the `of <selector>` syntax is limited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#browser_compatibility) as of now.

#### Old Answer

*Note: This answer was given prior the Selectors Level 4.*

The `:nth-child()` pseudo-class selector doesn't work on classes, it looks for the element itself. You'd need to wrap the `.container` divs by a wrapper and use the following:

```css
.wrapper div:nth-child(n+3) {
   /* put your styles here... */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/PY5Fe/)**.

### Clarifying on `:nth-child()`

Using `.container:nth-child(n+3)` may or may not work. Because, `:nth-child()` pseudo-class represents `nth` child element matching the selector (`.container` in this case).

If the `.container` element isn't the **nth-child** of its *parent*, it won't be selected.

From the [Spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#nth-child-pseudo):

> The `:nth-child(an+b)` pseudo-class notation represents an element
> that has `an+b-1` **siblings** before it in the document tree, for any
> positive integer or zero value of `n`, and has a parent element.

Consider this example:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>1st</div>
    <div>2nd</div>
    <div>3rd</div>
    <div class="container">4th</div>
    <div class="container">5th</div>
    <div class="container">6th</div>
    <div>7th</div>
    <div class="container">8th</div>
    <div>9th</div>
</div>
```

In this case, `.container:nth-child(2)` won't select the 2nd `div.container` element (which has `5th` content). Because that element is not the **2nd** child of its parent, in parent's children tree.

Also, `.container:nth-child(n+3)` will select all the `div.container` elements because `n` starts from `0` for the first element in the parent's children tree, and the first `div.container` is the **4th child** of its parent.

```
n starts from 0

n = 0: (0 + 3) = 3 => 3rd element
n = 1: (1 + 3) = 4 => 4th element
n = 2: (2 + 3) = 5 => 5th element
...
```

Hence `div.container:nth-child(n+3)` represents all the **3rd**, **4th**, **5th**, ... child elements matching `div.container` selector.

**[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/rGrFD/1/)**.

Comment: This looks like the correct answer. Thanks, I also did not know nth-child() can't work with class.

Comment: @FilipHuysmans That's because in your case, all the classes are the only children in their parent children tree.

Comment: I can't change the html because my app is dynamic. BTW, .container:nth-child(even) is working but your solution not? why?

Comment: Also Note I have, `<table class='main-container'><tr><td><div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div></td></tr></table>`

Comment: @user960567 Well, you could use `.main-container td :nth-child(n+3) { ... }`. [Seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/PY5Fe/4/).

Comment: `td :nth-child(n+2), td :nth-child(n+1)` works but `td :nth-child(n+3)` not? why? BTW, I have ` .main-container
                                    {
                                        page-break-inside: avoid;
                                    }`

Comment: @HashemQolami, I still don't get why Filip's solution doesn't work... do you have a demo to show me why it won't work... (just as a lesson).

Comment: @LinkinTED I prepared a [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/fZGvH/167/) to demonstrate the `nth-child` logic. Take a look at the comments in CSS panel.

Comment: @HashemQolami, thank you. The nth-child will look at all div's and not only the .red class! Clarifies it for me.

Comment: I also added more details to the answer just for clarification.

Comment: Thanks! This answer cleared many things. One query I have related to nth-child is that if I put a space just before ':nth-child(n)', the resultant elements are differ than in case of no space. e.g. 'div#someID:nth-child(n)' and 'div#someID :nth-child(n)' will have different results. Can you provide some details on this also in your answer?

Comment: @Shivam Thanks for the comment. Actually the whitespace you mentioned is a _descendant combinator_ which is totally different from the OP's question. It searches for the elements matching the `:nth-child(n)` that are descendants of element matching the `div#someID` selector. For more info on _combinators_ please refer to [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#combinators) document.

Comment: Thank you for the link.

Comment: `n+3` is for elements bigger than 2, but how to take elements that are smaller than 3?

Comment: @soundwave If you mean how to select the `'b' first` elements, you can use `-n+b` - [source](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#:~:text=The%20value%20a%20can%20be%20negative). Please let me know if I understood you correctly.

Comment: nth-child does work on classes. For example 
    :nth-child(4 of .my-class)

Comment: @mosaic Thanks! I updated the answer to cover the Selectors Level 4 changes in this matter.

Answer (score 23):

css:

```
.wrapper div:nth-child(n+3) {    /* you style*/   }
```

**Reason and Explanation**

```
 (0+3) = 3 = 3rd Element
 (1+3) = 4 = 4th Element
 (2+3) = 5 = 5th Element  and so on ... where n=0,1,2,3.....
```

[Live example >>](http://jsfiddle.net/PY5Fe/2/)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code.It will apply styles to all `.container` classes except 1 and 2:

```
.container+.container~.container{
   /*styles*/
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7CEVv/)

Comment: Not working? I have `<table class='main-container'><tr><td><div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div></td></tr></table>`

Comment: @user960567 works for me .Giving correct output in fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7CEVv/2/

Answer (score 2):

If it's just 1 and 2 you don't want the style applied to you can do something like this instead:

```
.container {
    background: yellow;
}

.container:first-child,
.container:first-child + .container {
    background: transparent;
}
```

The yellow background will apply to every container except for the first child and the one following it.

Answer (score 2):

```
.container ~.container{
     padding: 0
     margin: 0
 }
```

I used to apply all classes except first class.

Answer (score 1):

For those after a dynamic solution (if you don't want to hard-code the column widths etc), I've published a [javascript solution](https://github.com/CharlieHawker/tableColumnFreeze.js), based on [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22035872).

**[Working example](http://charliehawker.com/tableColumnFreeze.js/example.html)**

**Usage:**

```
// After including tableColumnFreeze.js
var freezer = document.getElementById('freezer');
new TableColumnFreeze(freezer);
```

**Markup:**

```
<div id="freezer">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th><th>Column 3</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><th>Frozen</th><td>Not frozen</td><td>Not frozen</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Frozen</th><td>Not frozen</td><td>Not frozen</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Frozen</th><td>Not frozen</td><td>Not frozen</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Frozen</th><td>Not frozen</td><td>Not frozen</td></tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```