# Hiding incremental values between a range

Tags: jquery, css

So taking the following HTML:-

```
<div id="news-archive">
    <div id="blog-1" class="blog-wrapper">some content</div>
    <div id="blog-2" class="blog-wrapper">some content</div>
    <div id="blog-3" class="blog-wrapper">some content</div>
    <div id="blog-4" class="blog-wrapper">some content</div>
    <!-- and so on -->
</div>
```

And lets say the blog increment continues to 150.

Is it possible with CSS to only show the first 6 divs, i.e. `#blog-1` through to `#blog-6` and then hide the rest or is this a jQuery job?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS nth-child for greater than and less than](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035799/css-nth-child-for-greater-than-and-less-than)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this in CSS using the `nth-child` selector:

```
#news-archive div {
    display: none;
}
#news-archive div:nth-child(-n+6) {
    display: block;
}
```

```css
#news-archive div {
    display: none;
}
#news-archive div:nth-child(-n+6) {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="news-archive">
    <div id="blog-1" class="blog-wrapper">some content 1</div>
    <div id="blog-2" class="blog-wrapper">some content 2</div>
    <div id="blog-3" class="blog-wrapper">some content 3</div>
    <div id="blog-4" class="blog-wrapper">some content 4</div>
    <div id="blog-5" class="blog-wrapper">some content 5</div>
    <div id="blog-6" class="blog-wrapper">some content 6</div>
    <div id="blog-7" class="blog-wrapper">some content 7</div>
    <div id="blog-8" class="blog-wrapper">some content 8</div>
    <div id="blog-9" class="blog-wrapper">some content 9</div>
    <div id="blog-10" class="blog-wrapper">some content 10</div>
    <div id="blog-11" class="blog-wrapper">some content 11</div>
    <div id="blog-12" class="blog-wrapper">some content 12</div>
</div>
```

However it may be worth you using AJAX to load only the required elements instead, as loading 140+ items on the page which will never be used will affect performance for no benefit.

Comment: Awesome thanks Rory, just what I needed, will use AJAX as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the rest of the `divs` with `css` by adding another class to them. Like this

```
//CSS class
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Then add the class to the rest of the `divs` you want to hide like this

```
<div id="blog-7" class="blog-wrapper hide">some content</div>
<!-- and so on -->
```