# How to use CSS to display only three items on a mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

If I have a screen that will display 6 items in the computer version, but below the mobile device (414px), only three will be displayed.

Is there a way to achieve this effect through css if the HTML structure is not changed?

```css
.list {
  width: 300px;
}
.list .item {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #fed71a;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
   <li class="item">about1</li>
   <li class="item">about1</li>
   <li class="item">about1</li>
   <li class="item">about1</li>
   <li class="item">about1</li>
   <li class="item">about1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22035872/12733135

Comment: Hello~ I don’t know if my understanding is incorrect, is that right?
https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/YzxOZgW

Comment: I didn't understand the question, you have 6 items in a `ul` and you want only 3 to be displayed if a mobile is used? If so then you can use media queries and use the property of `display: hidden;`

Comment: @AWEI looks good

Comment: @AWEI if it works for you then it works... what's the problem?

Comment: @RudyTheWebDev yes - the question is selecting which ones to show/hide in the media query

Comment: Yes, I have solved my problem, thank you

Comment: Do you mean on 414px screens width and below you want only first three `li`s display?

Comment: @RudyTheWebDev `display` doesn't have a `hidden`value. `visibility`does, but here we need `display: none;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.

```css
.list {
  width: 300px;
}

.list .item {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #fed71a;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

@media (max-width: 414px) {
  .item:nth-child(4),
  .item:nth-child(5),
  .item:nth-child(6) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">about1</li>
  <li class="item">about1</li>
  <li class="item">about1</li>
  <li class="item">about1</li>
  <li class="item">about1</li>
  <li class="item">about1</li>
</ul>
```