# Justifying and centering elements specifing to a column or row

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid layout, and I'm curious if I can justify all of the elements in just my first column to the right, or if I can align elements specific to one row, without having to define properties for all elements, rather just to define the box alignments for specific rows or columns.

I tried putting align-self or justify-self for every element, but that't just really inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Below sample code contains CSS selectors for 3rd column and 2nd row in a 3x3 grid. Retrieved from https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid and made use of the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3462301/5869805 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/22035872/5869805

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(3n) {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.grid-item:nth-child(n+4):not(:nth-child(n+7)) {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>  
</div>
```